# Is it possible to reuse generated columns in ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a script where I'm using ddply, as in the following example:

```
ddply(df, .(col),
function(x) data.frame(
col1=some_function(x$y),
col2=some_other_function(x$y)
)
)
```

Within ddply, is it possible to reuse col1 without calling the entire function again?

For example:

```
ddply(df, .(col),
function(x) data.frame(
col1=some_function(x$y),
col2=some_other_function(x$y)
col3=col1*col2
)
)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Your second example is perfectly valid code and should work.  If you're using transform or summarise, it's a slightly different situation because of the way those functions are written.

Comment: I receive an error message akin to what follows:
Error in data.frame(...,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: X, Y

when I try to use code like my second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a whole function to play with! Doesn't have to be a one-liner! This should work:

```
ddply(df, .(col), function(x) {
  tmp <- some_other_function(x$y)
  data.frame(
    col1=some_function(x$y),
    col2=tmp,
    col3=tmp
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize how scalable ddply was. It's my first day actually making use of it. I'm trying to move away from "for" loops. Dirk, pointed the function and the plyr package out to me in another question and I've been making great use of it.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a good candidate for `data.table` using the scoping rules of the `j` component. See [FAQ 2.8 for details](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf).

From the FAQ

> No anonymous function is passed to
>   the j. Instead, an anonymous body is passed to the j.

So, for your case

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,{
 col1=some_function(y)
 col2=some_other_function(y)
 col3= col1 *col2
 list(col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3)
 }, by = col]
```

or a slightly more direct way :

```
DT[,list(
 col1=col1<-some_function(y)
 col2=col2<-some_other_function(y)
 col3=col1*col2
 ), by = col]
```

This avoids one repetition each of `col1` and `col2`, and avoids two repeats of `col3`; repetition is something we strive to reduce in `data.table`. The `=` followed by `<-` might initially look cumbersome. That allows the following syntactic sugar, though :

```
DT[,list(
 "Projected return (%)"=      col1<-some_function(y),
 "Investment ($m)"=           col2<-some_other_function(y),
 "Return on Investment ($m)"= col1*col2
 ), by = col]
```

where the output can be sent directly to latex or html, for example.

Comment: +1 for the alternative. What's the hype with DT? I haven't read about it yet.

Comment: Im not sure how lexical scoping comes in here? And shouldn't col3 be col1*col2 to avoid the recall?

Comment: True, was really only wanting the bit on it being a *body* of a function evaluated using the scoping rules.

Comment: @mnel Added some more in edit. Hope ok. When others have editted my answers I think I've noticed that S.O. doesn't automatically tell me. Does it for you?

Comment: That is really nifty! And yes, I seem to get notifications about edits.

Comment: @MatthewDowle it's a light coloured number on where you see notifications for the inbox. When you click on the dropdown, you'll see a tab called notifications, that's where they list edits amoung other things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible, but it shouldn't matter too much, because at that point it's not an aggregation function anymore. For example:

```
#use summarize() in ddply()
data.means <- ddply(data, .(groups), summarize, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), n = length(x))
data.means$se <- data.means$sd / sqrt(data.means$n)
data.means$Upper <- data.means$mean + (data.means$SE * 1.96)
data.means$Lower <- data.means$mean - (data.means$SE * 1.96)
```

So I didn't calculate the SEs directly, but it wasn't so bad calculating it outside of `ddply()`. If you really wanted to, you could also do

```
ddply(data, .(groups), summarize, se = sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))
```

Or to put it in terms of your example

```
ddply(df, .(col), summarize,
      col1=some_function(y),
      col2=some_other_function(y)
      col3=some_function(y)*some_other_function(y)
    )
```